# SQL Select Concat between 2 numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, concatenation, difference-between-rows

I work with SQL Server 2012 and need a concatenate between 2 different columns.

eg:

```
3 and 7 = 34567
or 1 and 4 = 1234
or 2 and 2 = 2
```

When I use the Concat Function, I am just able to Concate the first and the last number. But I need the numbers between, too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query. Here firstcolumn =3 and secondcolumn=7

```
SELECT t.Id, 
       ,STUFF((SELECT '' + CAST( n AS VARCHAR(50)) [text()]
         FROM (SELECT DISTINCT n = number 
                FROM master..[spt_values] 
                WHERE number >= firstcolumn AND number <= secondcolumn
                )a
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'') List_Output
FROM tablename t
```

Comment: Yes, i have missed the part that he wants to concatenate the digits to a single varchar.

Comment: Bit late, but there is a simple way to do it using `substring()` function.

Answer (score 2):

There are [multiple ways to generate sequences](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) in sql-server. Here is a simple that doesn't need a number-table:

```
WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP (2000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) 
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n
)
SELECT n FROM Numbers 
WHERE n BETWEEN 3 AND 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive query that will go from start to end recursively and generate the string you want or an `INTEGER` value:

```
DECLARE @start  INT = 3 
DECLARE @end    INT = 7
DECLARE @int_value  INT = 0
DECLARE @str_value  VARCHAR(100) = '';

WITH rec AS (
    SELECT @start AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  val + 1
    FROM    rec 
    WHERE   val < @end
)
SELECT  @str_value = CONCAT(@str_value, val), 
        @int_value = @int_value * 10 + val
FROM    rec

SELECT  @str_value, @int_value
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Itzik's style

```
declare @values varchar(100)='', @from int, @to int
select @from=3, @to=7
;WITH 
   n0 AS (SELECT 0 AS number UNION ALL SELECT 0), 
   n1 AS (SELECT 0 AS number FROM n0 AS a CROSS JOIN n0 AS b),
   n2 AS (SELECT 0 AS number FROM n1 AS a CROSS JOIN n1 AS b),
   n3 AS (SELECT 0 AS number FROM n2 AS a CROSS JOIN n2 AS b)

   select @values=@values+ltrim(sno) from 
   (select row_number() over (order by number) as sno from n3) as t
   where sno between @from and @to 
   select @values as [values]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `SUBSTRING()` function([Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a01b/2)):

```
--Declare sample table
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int identity, numCol1 int, numCol2 int)

--Add some values
INSERT @T (numCol1, numCol2)
VALUES (3, 7), (1, 4), (2, 2)

--Actual Query
SELECT *,  SUBSTRING('123456789', numCol1,  numCol2 - numCol1  + 1) Number
FROM @T
```

Above query works only with single digit numbers. [Modified version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf145/3) (below) to work with numbers like 34, 78

```
SELECT *,  
       SUBSTRING('123456789', CONVERT(int, LEFT(numCol1,1)), 
          CONVERT(int, RIGHT(numCol2, 1)) - convert(int, LEFT(numCol1,1))  + 1) YourNumber
FROM @T
```

Note: Number column is returning a `string`, can be converted to an `int` using `convert()` function

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the Answer.
I am going to use the answer from @Mukesh Kalgude.
So, my full query is the follow:

```
select 
DayFrom,DayTo,
STUFF((SELECT TOP 7'' + CAST( n AS VARCHAR(50)) [text()]
         FROM (SELECT DISTINCT n = number 
                FROM master..[spt_values] 
                WHERE number >= DayFrom AND DayTo <= 7
                )a
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'') List_Output
from SwitchProfilePairs
```

The result is 
dayFrom = 1 day To = 1 But the List_Output is 1234567